# dojotype dijit.form.Button not working on single click in IE9 and IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, dojo

I have a dojotype=dijit.form.Button, it is working perfectly in firefox and chrome but not working in IE9 and IE 10 in single click. I have to click twice to make it work. My code for button is as below:

```
 **<button dojoType='dijit.form.Button' id='insertButton' <?php echo $this->perm_insert ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ; ?> onClick=clickInsert()>Insert</button>**
```

I have tried several things and got that when I modify my code as written below, its started working on single click on IE also:

```
 **<button type='button' id='insertButton' <?php echo $this->perm_insert ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ; ?> onClick=clickInsert()>Insert</button>**
```

All I want to know, is what is the basic difference in both the type. In both the cases I have used button tag, only type is different. Also, why dojoType is not working? 
Also , can I fix it using dojo button?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1.  What does the dojo button look like when its rendered?  is the widget being parsed? 2.  What version of dojo are you working with?

Comment: Dojo 1.9, Dojo button is exactly the same, just it corner is not curved. When I click the first time, the button just got the focus and on second click onClick event getting called.